# Adding styles to d3 tooltips

Tags: d3.js

Referencing the following method to add tooltips to d3 elements:

http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/1016860

I am attempting to modify the font using the attr property:

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .style("position", "absolute")
  .style("z-index", "10")
  .style("visibility", "hidden")
  .attr('font-size', '8')               <-- does not work
  .attr('color', 'red')                 <-- does not work
  .text("");
```

This however does not work.

What is the right way to do this ?

Plnkr here: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/B33mAZPMdTRTm6imHxYq?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `font-size` and `color` properties should be set with the `style()` function, not `attr()`:

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .style("position", "absolute")
  .style("z-index", "10")
  .style("visibility", "hidden")
  .style('font-size', '8px')
  .style('color', 'red')
  .text("");
```

Comment: This is an issue in this case in particular because HTML is more picky about  `.attr()` vs. `.style()` -- in SVG, it usually doesn't matter which one you use, but in HTML you have to use `.style()` for anything related to styling.